# azure existing vpn and gateway, add address space

Tags: azure, vpn, gateway

I have an existing side-to-side connectivity azure gateway with one local network having three different address spaces to connect to the intranet of a customer. This is up and running, working like a charm.

Now I have the necessity for a fourth address space. I did add it, closed the gateways' connection and created it again. It doesn't look like the new address space is being considered.

Is it really necessary to remove and recreate the whole gateway, pass over the newly created key to the customer to make this working? I couldnt find anything in the documentation of Azure here.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Why downrate without comments? There is actually no documentation about that behavior. If you have to say something, do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The gateway needs to recreated, just close/ recreate connection does not help. For recreation of the gateway the new preshared key has to be passed over to the owner of the network again.
2. the user interface of the address spaces is implemented in a strange way. It only allows the last address to be edited. To edit a previous one, the other(s) have to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

> If you have a gateway connection and want to add or remove the IP address prefixes contained in your local network gateway, you need to do the following steps, in order. This results in some downtime for your VPN connection. When modifying IP address prefixes, you don't need to delete the VPN gateway. You only need to remove the connection.

[To modify local network gateway IP address prefixes - existing gateway connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell#modify)

1. Remove the connection.

```
Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name MyGWConnectionName -ResourceGroupName MyRGName
```

2. Modify the address prefixes for your local network gateway.

Set the variable for the LocalNetworkGateway

```
$local = Get-AzureRmLocalNetworkGateway -Name MyLocalNetworkGWName -ResourceGroupName MyRGName
```

Modify the prefixes.

```
Set-AzureRmLocalNetworkGateway -LocalNetworkGateway $local `
-AddressPrefix @('10.0.0.0/24','20.0.0.0/24','30.0.0.0/24')
```

3. Create the connection. In this example, we configure an IPsec connection type. When you recreate your connection, use the connection type that is specified for your configuration. For additional connection types, see the PowerShell cmdlet page.

Set the variable for the VirtualNetworkGateway.

```
$gateway1 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -Name RMGateway  -ResourceGroupName MyRGName
```

Create the connection. This example uses the variable $local that you set in step 2.

```
New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name MyGWConnectionName `
-ResourceGroupName MyRGName -Location 'West US' `
-VirtualNetworkGateway1 $gateway1 -LocalNetworkGateway2 $local `
-ConnectionType IPsec `
-RoutingWeight 10 -SharedKey 'abc123'
```